# How to row bind all cases of a particular weekday in a given year-month into an R dataset

Tags: r, data.table, rbind

I have data that includes a date and day of week.

- I would like to identify all instances of a particular weekday that match the given year/month/weekday
  in the original data.
  For instance if the first record has the date "2010-07-05" which is a Thursday, I want to rowbind all Thursdays
  that occur in July of 2010 to my original dataset.
- While adding those new rows, I also want to fill in those new rows with values from the original data for all columns, except one.  The exception is a variable which indicates whether or not that row 
  was in the original dataset or not.

Example data:

(1) alldays -- this data includes all dates and weekdays for the appropriate years.

(2) dt1 -- this is the example dataset that includes the date `Adate`, and day of week `dow` that will be used to identify the year/month/weekday and then look for all dates within that same month for the given weekday.  For example - all Thursdays in July of 2017 will need to row bound to the original data.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

alldays <- data.table (date = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"),
                                  as.Date("2011-12-31"), by="days"))
alldays <- alldays %>%
  dplyr::mutate(year = lubridate::year(date), 
                month = lubridate::month(date), 
                day = lubridate::day(date),
                dow = weekdays(date))
setDT(alldays)
head(alldays)
        date year month day       dow
1 2010-01-01 2010     1   1    Friday
2 2010-01-02 2010     1   2  Saturday
3 2010-01-03 2010     1   3    Sunday
4 2010-01-04 2010     1   4    Monday
5 2010-01-05 2010     1   5   Tuesday
6 2010-01-06 2010     1   6 Wednesday
```

Here is an example of the primary dataset

```
id <- seq(1:2)
admit <- rep(1,2)
zip <- c(54123, 54789)
Adate <- as.Date(c("2010-07-15","2011-03-14"))
year <- c(2010, 2011)
month <- c(7,3)
day <- c(15,14)
dow <- c("Thursday","Monday")
dt1 <- data.table(id, admit, zip, Adate, year, month, day, dow)
dt1
#>    id admit   zip      Adate year month day      dow
#> 1:  1     1 54123 2010-07-15 2010     7  15 Thursday
#> 2:  2     1 54789 2011-03-14 2011     3  14   Monday
```

The resulting dataset should be:

```
   id admit   zip      Adate year month day      dow
1:  1     0 54123 2010-07-01 2010     7   1 Thursday
2:  1     0 54123 2010-07-08 2010     7   8 Thursday
3:  1     1 54123 2010-07-15 2010     7  15 Thursday
4:  1     0 54123 2010-07-22 2010     7  22 Thursday
5:  1     0 54123 2010-07-29 2010     7  29 Thursday
6:  2     0 54789 2011-03-07 2011     3   7   Monday
7:  2     1 54789 2011-03-14 2011     3  14   Monday
8:  2     0 54789 2011-03-21 2011     3  21   Monday
9:  2     0 54789 2011-03-28 2011     3  28   Monday
```

So we can see that the first date `dt1` 2010-07-15 associated with id=1, which was a Thursday fell within a month with 4 additional Thursday in that month which were added to the dataset.  The variable `admit` is the indicator of whether that row was in the original or subsequently added by virtue of the being matched.

I have tried first selecting the additional dates from `alldays` with matching weekdays but I am running into issues on how to rowbind those back into the original dataset while filling in the other values appropriately.  Eventually I will be running this on a dataset with about 300,000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
alldays[dt1[, .(id, zip, admit=0L, year, month, dow)], 
    on=.(year, month, dow), allow.cartesian=TRUE][
        dt1, on=.(id, date=Adate), admit := i.admit][]
```

output:

```
         date year month day      dow id   zip admit
1: 2010-07-01 2010     7   1 Thursday  1 54123     0
2: 2010-07-08 2010     7   8 Thursday  1 54123     0
3: 2010-07-15 2010     7  15 Thursday  1 54123     1
4: 2010-07-22 2010     7  22 Thursday  1 54123     0
5: 2010-07-29 2010     7  29 Thursday  1 54123     0
6: 2011-03-07 2011     3   7   Monday  2 54789     0
7: 2011-03-14 2011     3  14   Monday  2 54789     1
8: 2011-03-21 2011     3  21   Monday  2 54789     0
9: 2011-03-28 2011     3  28   Monday  2 54789     0
```

Comment: This looks like it should work.  However when I run that code I get an error message:  ```Error in `[.data.frame`(alldays, dt1[, .(id, zip, year, month, dow)],  : 
  unused argument (on = .(year, month, dow))```.  I am using data.table_1.12.8      @chinsoon12

Comment: @mpap you need to `setDT` for `alldays`

Comment: Oh man, yes using ```setDT(alldays) ``` allows it to work.  I didn't realize that when I used ```dplyr``` to break apart the year that it would output a data.frame and drop the data.table class.  Thanks.  I will amend the sample data above.

Comment: This also worked on my larger dataset.  However my data has duplicate dates, so I had to add/edit  ```on=.(year, month, dow), allow.cartesian=TRUE]