# How to multiply rows so that I get a particular weekday of the previous 4 weeks and the following 4 weeks

Tags: r, date

I have data that includes a date and day of week.

I would like to identify the 4 instances of a particular weekday that immediately precede the date in the original data and the 4 instances of the same weekday that immediately follow the date in the original data. For instance if the first record has the date "2010-05-03" which is a Tuesday, I want to rowbind the 4 Tuesdays that occur in April of 2010 and the 4 Tuesdays that occur in May of 2010 to my original dataset. I want to do this for each record in the original data and get a single dataset containing all original records and the records with the added dates as a result.

While adding those new rows, I also want to fill in those new rows with values from the original data for all columns, except one. The exception is a variable, called 'event', which indicates whether or not that row was in the original dataset or not.

Eventually, I want to randomly select 4 rows out of the 8 that were added to the original data per each original record, so that the final dataset has 5 rows per each original record (1 with the original date and 4 with the added and randomly selected dates).

Expected output

```
> head(dt1[, 1:7])
   id duplicate_ data di na      dow year month date_of_on
1:  1       <NA>       <NA>  Tuesday 2011     5 2011-05-03
2:  2       <NA>       <NA> Saturday 2011    12 2011-12-10


> head(dt3[1:10, 1:7])
         date year month day      dow id date_of_onset    event

1: 2011-04-05 2011     4   5  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03.      0
2: 2011-04-12 2011     4  12  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
3: 2011-04-19 2011     4  19  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
4: 2011-04-26 2011     4  26  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
5: 2011-05-03 2011     5   3  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       1
6: 2011-05-10 2011     5  10  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
7: 2011-05-17 2011     5  17  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
8: 2011-05-24 2011     5  24  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
9: 2011-05-31 2011     5  31  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
```

After randomly selecting 4 out the 8 rows added, it should look like this

```
> head(dt4[1:10, 1:7])
         date year month day      dow id date_of_onset    event
1: 2011-04-05 2011     4   5  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03.      0
2: 2011-04-19 2011     4  19  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
3: 2011-05-03 2011     5   3  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       1
4: 2011-05-10 2011     5  10  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
5: 2011-05-24 2011     5  24  Tuesday  1    2011-05-03       0
```

I found the following post partly useful, but not fully satisfying my query:[How to row bind all cases of a particular weekday in a given year-month into an R dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647242/how-to-row-bind-all-cases-of-a-particular-weekday-in-a-given-year-month-into-an)

Comment: Just to clarify, do want to process all dates in dt1 into a single output? Or do you want multiple outputs, one for each date? Thanks

Comment: I want to process all dates in the dataset and get a single dataset as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could try the following.

Using `pmap_dfr` iterate through each row of your data.frame. In this case, you can pass all of your column data `...` through the function.

The `sample_dates` will sample from a date vector containing dates 4 weeks before and 4 weeks after the event.

The result will be placed into a temporary data.frame, with `event` of 0, and combined with original data (with `event` of 1).

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2),
  dow = c("Tuesday", "Saturday"),
  date_of_onset = as.Date(c("2011-05-03", "2011-12-10"))
)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

df %>%
  pmap_dfr(function(...) {
    x <- tibble(...)
    sample_dates <- sample(c(seq.Date(x$date_of_onset - weeks(4), by = "week", length.out = 4),
                             seq.Date(x$date_of_onset + weeks(1), by = "week", length.out = 4)), 4)
    return(bind_rows(mutate(x, event = 1),
                     left_join(tibble(id = x$id, date_of_onset = sample_dates, event = 0), 
                               select(x, -date_of_onset), 
                               by = "id")
    ))
  }) %>%
  arrange(id, date_of_onset)
```

**Output**

```
      id dow      date_of_onset event
   <dbl> <chr>    <date>        <dbl>
 1     1 Tuesday  2011-04-19        0
 2     1 Tuesday  2011-05-03        1
 3     1 Tuesday  2011-05-17        0
 4     1 Tuesday  2011-05-24        0
 5     1 Tuesday  2011-05-31        0
 6     2 Saturday 2011-11-19        0
 7     2 Saturday 2011-11-26        0
 8     2 Saturday 2011-12-10        1
 9     2 Saturday 2011-12-24        0
10     2 Saturday 2012-01-07        0
```